# Powershell script to check for disconnected sessions that have been disconnected for more then 12 hours

Tags: powershell, citrix

I am trying to write a Powershell script that I can schedule to run at 5am to kick disconnected users off my Citrix servers.

I have found this example:

```
foreach ($_ in get-content servers.txt) {(gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $_).Win32Shutdown(4)}
```

But am unsure how to edit it to find out if they have been disconnected for more then 12 hours.

If anyone could help that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Citrix Powershell snapin like below.  This script will go through all the sessions in the farm and kick out disconnected ones.  You will need to install the Citrix Powershell commands on the box you run this from.  Is this for Citrix XenApp 4.5 or higher?  Citrix versions below XenApp 4.5 will need to use MFCOM for this but you can still use Powershell.

```
Add-PSSnapin Citrix.XenApp.Commands
Get-XASession | Where-Object { $_.State -eq "Disconnected" } | Stop-XASession
```

Answer (score -1):

if the goal is to disconnect users "after" 12 hrs, why dont you implement that in GPO rather than scheduled task?

I usually set GPO to to disconnect user after 2 hrs of idle time, then log out after 30min.